# MySQL doesn't allow external connections

Tags: mysql, external, connection

I have a problem with my MYSQL that doesn't allow external connections .
 I try to connect an website to an mysql that is on another server .

What I did was to comment in my.cnf `skip-external-locking` and `bind-adress` and it still doesn't work .

I also put the host `%` and also doesn't work .

When I try to connect from puty with `mysql -h ip -u user -p` I get this output:
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fulgeratii'@'myip' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Have you tried putting in the respective IP's into the allowed hosts for mysql remote connections in cpanel or similar?

Comment: Try to set `bind-adress` to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: yes, explicit # rem skip networking, 0.0.0.0, restart. `select user,host from mysql.user`

Comment: `# skip-networking` ... http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth checking that the user you are trying to use has the correct grants on the mysql server.

To be sure i would try temporarily using the root user or granting all to your user like so:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'fulgeratii'@'localhost';
```

At the very least it will eliminate the possibility of a MySQL permission problem

Comment: In his case, it would be better to use `%` instead of `localhost`